# Scraping the yahoo Group data

Tags: web-scraping, yahoo-api

I need to export the data from the yahoo group, Is there any API to export the post data like list of the members, topic name, topic author, total response to that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no official API for Yahoo! Groups.